# submit button in selenium without id and value

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have a button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

I have already tested all this but without success

```
# browser.find_element_by_class_name('fa fa-search').click()
# browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/form/div/button').click()
# WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="RechAvFormRadio"]/div/button'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with css selector like this :

```
button.btn.btn-default.waves-effect.waves-light
```

or xpath

```
//button[contains(@class,'btn btn-default waves-effect waves-light')]
```

or

```
//i[contains(@class,'fa fa-search')]/parent::button
```

**PS :** Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

**Code trial 1 :**

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[contains(@class,'fa fa-search')]/parent::button").click()
```

**Code trial 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[contains(@class,'fa fa-search')]/parent::button"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Traceback:

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default waves-effect waves-light">...</button> is not clickable at point (674, 578). Other element would receive the click: <div class="col-8 text-center">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)

Comment: Is there any overlaying web element ?

Comment: it looks like yes

Comment: If possible can you share page URL  ?